# A weird problem in flutter FutureBuilder UI Update

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a weird problem in update my UI with FutureBuilder widget.
After fetching data from server, my list and my title updated correctly, but my filter section didn't update until I scroll the list.

[image]

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: HotelAppTheme.buildLightTheme(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              },
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //**** This portion Update Correctly */
                  getAppBarUI(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: NestedScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      headerSliverBuilder:
                          (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                        return <Widget>[
                          SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  getSearchBarUI(),
                                ],
                              );
                            }, childCount: 1),
                          ),
                          SliverPersistentHeader(
                            pinned: true,
                            floating: true,
                            delegate: ContestTabHeader(
                              //***** This Portion Update Problem!!!! */
                              getFilterBarUI(totalCount),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ];
                      },
                      body: Container(
                          color:
                              HotelAppTheme.buildLightTheme().backgroundColor,
                          //****in getListUI I have FutureBuilder that Update My list and Variables
                          child: getListUI()),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

In FutureBuilder `getdata()` function, I called `Setstate()` function.

This is the 'getdata()' function. I believe 'getdata()' doesn't have any problems because the title gets updated.

```
Future<List<HotelListData>> getData() async {
    if (hotelList.isEmpty) {
      return await Remotecall().getExperts(widget.id).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          totalCount = value.totalCount ?? 0;
        });
        hotelList = value.entities!.map((val) {
          return HotelListData(
              imagePath: val.urlProfileImage ?? '',
              titleTxt: val.doctorFullName ?? '',
              subTxt: val.shortDescription ?? '');
        }).toList();
        return hotelList;
      });
    } else
      return hotelList;
  }
```

Comment: That is not enough code to help you. We need to see the code where you actually call your API, update your state and then call setState().

Comment: I updated question and add getdata() function